# How can I change an Icon in flutter when i add a new Entry in my Database?

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

So i set up a working Realtime Database, to which i can add entries. Now i want to notify the user whenever a new entry was added to the Database by adding a little Red Dot to the Icon in the BottomNavigationBar which disappears again when the user has clicked it. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Hey @Nkleins, i would suggest you to dig out something called as `UploadTask`, basically whenever you are uploading something to firebase they go via something called as `UploadTask` (they are  readily available in firebase core package) and every upload task have a event listener which listens to the upload changes  (like  total bytes transferred, upload pause, upload resume etc) you can add a `.whenComplete()` method after the upload task to check when your upload is complete, after that you can just use a `setState({});` to change your icon.

Comment: Also noting about the red dot you need after uploading, you can achieve it using flutter badges, just wrap around any widget with flutter badge to give is a notification type red dot or a number.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the badge package to achieve this. You will have to ensure the state updates using your own state management. If the user goes to the notification screen, you will need to trigger an update to mark notifications as read.

```
 return Badge(
          showBadge: unreadNotifications > 0,
          badgeContent: Text(
            '$unreadNotifications',
            style: kTextStyle,
          ),
          position: const BadgePosition(
            top: -3,
            end: 3,
          ),
          child: IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(
              Icons.notifications,
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushNamed(context, NotificationScreen.id);
            },
          ),
        );
```